# Tesseract don't output the first zero in 025575 of this image. How can make it print it with the first zero in it?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Tesseract don't output the first zero in 025575 of this image. It on only outputs 25575.

Here is what I tried:

This is the sn_img:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

sn_img = cv2.imread('sn.png')

sn_resize = cv2.resize(sn_img, (600, 200))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(sn_resize, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 170, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 9, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])
sharp_img = cv2.filter2D(thresh, -1, kernel)

# Invert and apply slight Gaussian blur
res = 255 - sharp_img
res = cv2.GaussianBlur(res, (3, 3), 0)

# Perform OCR
custom_config = r'--oem 1 --psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, config=custom_config)

try:
    data = int(data)
except ValueError:
    pass

print(f"the sn is {data}")

cv2.imshow('sn', sn_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the output of my code:

[image]

I expect it to print the 6 digits ---> 025575

Comment: Try to remove the line data = int(data). Maybr that transforms the string "025575" to an integer 25575.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use black & white and your tesseract output is a string. If you convert a str() to int() you lost the leading zero's:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Image manipulation
# Commands https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php
mag_img = r'D:\Programme\ImageMagic\magick.exe'
con_bw = r"D:\Programme\ImageMagic\convert.exe" 

in_file = r'ZeroNumber.png'
out_file = r'ZeroNumber_bw.png'

# Play with black and white and contrast for better results
process = subprocess.run([con_bw, in_file, "-resize", "140%","-threshold","60%", out_file])

# Text ptocessing
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread(out_file)

# Parameters see tesseract doc 
custom_config = r'--psm 7 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=01234567890' 

tex = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
print(tex)

with open("number.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(tex)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(4000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[image]